# Simulation Error (MULTISIM)

Tags: simulation, error, multisim

I am trying to make a basic invertor circuit using MESFETS the following figure shows the actual circuit but when i connect in multisim software it shows simulation error can anyone help me how to fix it.[image]

[image: Original Circuit]

[image: MULTISIM Connection]

[image: error message]

Comment: Tech D - Hi, Currently your question breaks the [site rule on referencing](/help/referencing) material copied/adapted from elsewhere. To comply with that rule, please [edit] the question & add the **name** of the PDF / video / webpage (etc.) which is the source of the original schematic, and its **link**. Or, if the source is not online, then add a normal, full citation inc. title, author(s), publication etc. for the research paper. Also please remember it's your responsibility to follow that rule in future too. TY (Please see the [tour] & [help] as site rules here differ from typical forums.)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wire the low point of Q3 ... it should not work.

My levels are not the "same" as yours.

[image]

And here is the "level" shifting ...

[image]